# What causes "C2872 'ACCESS_MASK': ambiguous symbol"?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, include, ambiguous

I am having an error with my Visual Studio 2015 C++ project that occurs 39 times, which states:

> C2872  'ACCESS_MASK': ambiguous symbol

My issue is that the 'files' in which these are occurring are all Windows files, such as:

> winnt.h
>
> winuser.h
>
> winreg.h

The include section of one of the projects `.h` file is as follows:

```cpp
#pragma once;
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/cxcore.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <opencv/cvaux.h>//Background modeling header files

#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/videoio.hpp"
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/video.hpp>
#include <windef.h>
using namespace cv;
```

and the other `.h` file has the following includes:

```cpp
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <XnCppWrapper.h>//OpenNI
using namespace cv;  

#include <iostream>  
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std ;
```

Is there perhaps an error due to having "using namespace ..." more than once?

The only other error that I am encountering is also from the winnt.h file, I am not sure if it is related but have included it just in case, and it is as follows :

> C1189 #error: "No Target Architecture"

I have tried changing around the included Windows files, as well as the `using namespace cv`, as some others have suggested, but have had no success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue solved by removing all cases where :

> using namespace cv

appeared. I did however have to add 'cv::' infront of all opencv related functions that had appeared in the code using the cv namespace.

The C1189 error was unrelated to this.

Answer (score 1):

I just moved opencv includes and using namespace cv next to all includes and before functions and main and its solved(after all includes and usings)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above and was still seeing this error. What fixed it for me was moving `#include <Windows.h>` before all the opencv header includes.

Answer (score 0):

Limiting the context of the namespace also works. That is:

```
namespace cv
{
....
}
```

This solution avoids adding 'cv::' that is quite tedious.